# Explicit computation of a Jacobian between hypersurfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, jacobian

Assume we work in a strictly convex domain $\Omega$ with $C^1$ boundary, say in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Given two points at the boundary $x$ and $y$, I first wanted to compute the corresponding unit vector linking $x$ to $y$. It is given by
$$ u = \frac{x - y}{\|x - y\|}.$$

On the other hand, because of the convexity assumption, we will always have that the condition $u \cdot n_x < 0$ is true for any vector of this kind (where $n_x$ is the outward normal vector to $\Omega$ at the point $x$).

Now I want to compute the Jacobian of the map
$$ \psi_x: \partial \Omega \to \{u \in \mathbb{S}^2, u \cdot n_x < 0 \}, $$
$$ y \to \psi_x(y) = \frac{x - y}{\|x - y\|}. $$

Note that this is indeed a $C^1$-diffeomorphism: we start for a point in an hypersurface and send it into another hypersurface, there are no dimensional issues.
I am having trouble computing this Jacobian matrix. I am not confortable at all with this kind of diffeomorphism between manifolds with boundary. Any clue on how to get started ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Jacobian matrix"? If it is a matrix you are after, you'll need some coordinate charts.

Comment: I want to perform the change of variable $y = \psi_x(y)$ in an integral over $y$ (or the other way around). The thing is I know that the determinant of the Jacobian matrix will not be zero since $\psi_x$ is indeed a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, but I would like to compute explicitely its value. Are you saying that it will in general be impossible to obtain it without going through coordinate charts ? And would I then need two charts, one for each manifold ?